Does SpringBoot makes bean selection based on variable name?
I recently decided to play a little bit with spring's Bean injection.
I have tried to provoke my app to fail when there were two, same type, Bean definition but application started to run.
I come up with that schema:
That's my simple interface
public interface Demo {

  String getMessage();
}

Two classes that implements that interface
@Service
public class DemoService implements Demo{

  private final DataRepo repo;

  DemoService(DataRepo repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }

  @Override
  public String getMessage() {
    return "Demo message from Demo Service";
  }
}

@Service
public class DemoSecondService implements Demo{

  private final DataRepo repo;

  DemoSecondService(DataRepo repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }

  @Override
  public String getMessage() {
    return "Demo message from DemoSecondService";
  }
}

That's my Controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoController {

  private final Demo demoSecondService; //(1)

  public DemoController(Demo demoSecondService) {
    this.demoSecondService = demoSecondService;
  }

  @GetMapping
  ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello", HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @GetMapping("/more")
  ResponseEntity<String> moreHello() {

    String message = demoSecondService.getMessage();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

So, Ive noticed that despite there are two Beans of type 'Demo', Spring doesnt have any problem with injecting beans in DemoController even when I dont use @Qualifier annotation. If only Demo variable in the Controller has name "demoSecondService" Spring injects DemoSecondService Bean, and if name of variable is demoService Spring automaticly injects DemoService Bean. This works even if variable has name like demoSecondServiceXXXXX. When the variable name changes to something completely different compared to Class name, like for example "newName" then as expected Spring tells that it can not choose which bean I would like to have injected in my Controller:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.domain.controller.DemoController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - demoSecondService: defined in file 
    - demoService: defined in file 

So why, in situation when variable name matches Class name, Spring can inject particular Bean?
Does SpringBoot makes bean selection based on variable name so we can use this without using @Qualifier?

As explained/mentioned in the reference guide of Spring Framework itself.

Letting qualifier values select against target bean names, within the type-matching candidates, does not require a @Qualifier annotation at the injection point. If there is no other resolution indicator (such as a qualifier or a primary marker), for a non-unique dependency situation, Spring matches the injection point name (that is, the field name or parameter name) against the target bean names and chooses the same-named candidate, if any (either by bean name or by associated alias).
Since version 6.1, this requires the -parameters Java compiler flag to be present.

So if there are multiple candidates Spring will try to match the bean-name against the injection point name (in this case the constructor argument).

If you want your application to fail due to the absence of the service, you could take advantage of the '@Qualifier' notation, you can pass a non-existent qualifier as a parameter, for example, you name your services with 'service_1' and 'service_2' but you try to inject the qualifier 'service_3' which does not exist.
@Service
@Qualifier("service_1")
public class DemoService implements Demo{

...
@Service
@Qualifier("service_2")
public class DemoSecondService implements Demo{

...
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    private final Demo demoSecondService;

    public DemoController(@Qualifier("service_3") Demo demoSecondService) {
        this.demoSecondService = demoSecondService;
    }

...

